# Об употреблении слов "либо", "не", "вправе"

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Либо возьми туза, либо не бери туза." означает высказывание "Ты вправе взять туза.",
- высказывание "Ты вправе взять туза." означает высказывание "Ты вправе не брать туза."?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, тут Искусственный Интеллект корячится... Скоро ли презентация?

Answer (score 0):

Указание "Либо возьми туза, либо не бери туза." означает высказывание "Ты вправе взять, либо не взять туза.". Высказывание "Ты вправе взять туза." означает высказывание "Ты вправе взять туза."(т.е. если хочешь взять туза - бери!).

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.

P.S. Предполагаю, что в Вашем сознании слово "вправе" (англ. аналог "may") является синонимом слова "должен" (англ. аналог "must").

Comment: Нет, ''вправе" не является синонимом "должен( англ. аналог "must").